# A transformation from one power series to another.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider two functions in form of power series:

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$$
$$G(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}x^n$$

and a function $H$ that transform $F$ to $G$ it is:

$$H(F(x))=G(x)$$

> How does $H$ look like?

If it is impossible to do, then consider a similar question:

Let radius of convergence of $G$ is $r$. How does $F$ should look like if we want to convergence of $G$ at $r$  ($|G(r)|<\infty$) ?

Regards

Comment: Here is an example where the radius of convergence of $G$ is finite.  Let $F(x)=e^x$.  Then $a_n=1$, and the radius of convergence of $G(x)$ is $R=1$.

Comment: Might be an idea to make the coefficients of $G$ different from $F$ ... $G(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\color{red}{b_n}}{n}x^n$ ... it is easier to do the coefficients of $G$ in terms of $H$ and $F$ ... there are some very beautiful combinatorial interpretations.

Comment: Try a tweaked Laplace transform.